# How can I make the interface to my enumerator accept feed?

Tags: ruby

From the [docs for Ruby v2.5](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-feed)

```
e = [1,2,3].map
p e.next           #=> 1
e.feed "a"
p e.next           #=> 2
e.feed "b"
p e.next           #=> 3
e.feed "c"
begin
  e.next
rescue StopIteration
  p $!.result      #=> ["a", "b", "c"]
end
```

But what about when I create my enum via `Enumerator.new`?

```
# a naive rework of the above enum
e2 = Enumerator.new do |y|
  [1,2,3].each do |x|
    y << x
  end
  # raise StopIteration, FED # <= how to get `FED`?
end

p e2.next           #=> 1
e2.feed "a"
p e2.next           #=> 2
e2.feed "b"
p e2.next           #=> 3
e2.feed "c"
begin
  e2.next
rescue StopIteration
  p $!.result      #=> nil
end
```

**How would I modify this to match the API?**

Things I have tried:

```
e2 = Enumerator.new do |y|
  [1,2,3].each do |x|
    @fed = yield
    y << x
  end
  raise StopIteration, @fed
end

e2 = Enumerator.new do |y|
  [1,2,3].each do |x|
    y << yield(x)
  end
  raise StopIteration, y
end

e2 = Enumerator.new do |y|
  enum = [1,2,3].each{|x| yield x }.to_enum
  y << enum.next
  raise StopIteration, y
end
```

Interestingly they all produce the same error when `feed` is called a second time:

```
# Ignoring all the other errors that jump up…
p e2.next           #=> 1
e2.feed "a"
# nil
p e2.next           #=> 2
e2.feed "b"
```

> TypeError: feed value already set

**TypeError: feed value already set** means it is collecting the the value *somewhere*, I just don't know how to access it.

The C source for #feed:

```
static VALUE
enumerator_feed(VALUE obj, VALUE v)
{
    struct enumerator *e = enumerator_ptr(obj);

    if (e->feedvalue != Qundef) {
        rb_raise(rb_eTypeError, "feed value already set");
    }
    e->feedvalue = v;

    return Qnil;
}
```

So `feedvalue` is my target. I've dropped into the operation of the method using Pry but can't find a method or variable that appears to relate to `feed` or `feedvalue`. [Rubinius makes this available explicitly](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/enumerator.rb#L23) (at least as an instance variable).

I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example is enumerator with a yield method of `:map`:

```
e = [1,2,3].map
=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:map>
```

Your second example is an enumerator with yield method of `:each`.

```
e2 = Enumerator.new do |y|
  [1,2,3].each do |x|
    y << x
  end
  # raise StopIteration, FED # <= how to get `FED`?
end
=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x007fa69b056b50>:each>
```

You should use [to_enum](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/to_enum) or [enum_for](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/enum_for) with the yield method of your choice:

```
[1,2,3].to_enum(:map)
=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:map>
```

Using `::new` in the manner below is now deprecated, so I would *NOT* recommend using it in favor of `to_enum` or `enum_for` which offer the same functionality:

```
Enumerator.new([1,2,3], :map)
```

### Summary

To sum this up, `#map` is the method being called by your first iterator, and when it is [called](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/enumerator.rb#L83), the [return values](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/enumerator.rb#L89) of it will decide the value of the result. When using `#each` like your other examples, it doesn't matter what you end your block (`#feed`) with since it won't affect the return value of `#each`.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The reason your first example works the way it does is because you've used #map which "passes the array's elements to "yield" and collects the results of "yield" as an array." There's an interesting note about it in Enumerator#feed http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-feed

Anyway, your custom enumerator will behave the same way as the Array in your first example if you also call `map` on it:

```
e2 = Enumerator.new { |y|
  [1,2,3].each do |x|
    y << x
  end
}.map

p e2.next           #=> 1
e2.feed "a"
p e2.next           #=> 2
e2.feed "b"
p e2.next           #=> 3
e2.feed "c"
begin
  e2.next
rescue StopIteration
  p $!.result      #=> ["a", "b", "c"]
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Cody's answer got the nod because its last para gave me the Eureka moment that my dull brain needed! Why one thing unlocks the mind but another doesn't…? Anyway, a helpful and insightful answer. Thanks again.